# Particle size as key frame

Tags: particles

I want to render a scene with 300 frames. I have particles included and in frame 1 I want to have particle size 0.001 growing linear until frame 300 to 0.05.

I am already aware how to use keyframes for rotation, but here I seem to fail.

[image]

The parameter I am talking about is in the lower left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While i am sure you have a reason to use the older version of Blender (update is much recommended though).

That said, you should be able to get it done by doing the following:

1. Go to frame 1, where the scale is supposed to be 0.001
2. Enter the value of 0.001 and then with the mouse over the **scale** field, press <kbd>I</kbd> to set a keyframe for that attribute at frame 1.
3. Now jump to frame 300 and enter the new value (0.05) for the scale and again with the mouse over the **scale** field press <kbd>I</kbd> to set another keyframe.

If you now play the animation, the scale value will be interpolated between 0.001 and 0.05 over the run of 300 frames. If you want a linear interpolation, you need to go in the graph editor and under **key** menu -> **Interpolation Mode** -> **Linear**. Or just press <kbd>T</kbd> and select **Linear**, like in the picture below.
[image]

I packed all in a little visual demonstration:
[image]

Happy Blending